# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch

Tags: batch

Running below code in anonymous window

```
 Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new s360_batchDocumentEmailWeekly(),10);
```

but its throwing above error.

```
  global class s360_batchDocumentEmailWeekly {
  global String query = '';
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
      query = 'select Id,Platform__c,Send_Revision_Email__c from Document__c 
      where Send_Revision_Email__c = true ';
      system.debug('>>>>' + query);
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List <Document__c> scope) {}
  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

  } }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few things wrong.

1. For a batch, you have to implement Database.Batchable interface.

   ```
   global class s360_batchDocumentEmailWeekly implements 
   Database.Batchable<sObject>{
     global String query = '';
     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
         query = 'select Id,Platform__c,Send_Revision_Email__c from Document__c 
         where Send_Revision_Email__c = true ';
         system.debug('>>>>' + query);
         return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
     }
     global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List <Document__c> scope) {

     }
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: ufff.. I dont how I missed this one. Error itself says about this interface but i dint catch it...Thanks